# How to provide copy-protection for Android free apps

Tags: android, copy-protection

i am providing copy protection for Android paid applications by using Android Market Licensing mechanism. But it supports only for the paid applications. How can i provide copy-protection to Free application. Is there any alternatives ? Please help me.

ThanQ.

Comment: Why would you like to protect free applications? They can be downloaded anyways by everyone

Comment: How can i know number of downloads, if the app copied from one to another.

Comment: Perhaps you should rely on something like Google Analytics instead of the Market to supply your number of downloads, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a free app, then you don't need copy protection.

It sounds like what you are looking for is analytical tracking.  Check out [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) or [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/).

Comment: Hi Denny thankq for ur reply it is useful to me.google analytics sounds like tracking app how many user using that and all right.but for me market downloads is very import means if any user using app they should download app from market only